# Radar chart Excel, showing blank value as zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On a radar graph I would like it to not display any line if a value is zero. In order to do this I wrapped an iferror around the averageifs, however the radar graph shows the blank as zero rather than missing value. As a result, it shows the line.

```
=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGEIFS(DATA2017s!$G:$G,DATA2017s!$C:$C,Datasource!$C$2,DATA2017s!$B:$B,"Self"),2),"")
```

Comment: Use `NA()` instead of `""`.

Comment: You the man Jeeped!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `=IFERROR(ROUND(AVERAGEIFS(DATA2017s!$G:$G,DATA2017s!$C:$C,Datasource!$C$2,DATA2017s!$B:$B,"Self"),2),(NA())`

The value will return N/A instead of empty values.

Comment: It is the right answer, however it was answered by Jeeped